# droppable draggable append to position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

When i drop the draggable div in the drop zone, it is going to the top left corner. Then then one after goes below it.

I need it so if i drop it in the middle of the drop zone, then it will append when i left it.
So i am trying to use the positions and setting the css but its not working

here is my js

```
$('.tab-list img').draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });

    $('#main').droppable({
        drop:function(event, ui) {
            var item = $(ui.draggable);

            var add;
            if(item.data('itemstate') == 'rectangle'){
                add = '<div class="pi-rectangle"></div>';
            }
            $(add).css('left', ui.position.left);
            $(add).css('top', ui.position.top);
            console.log(ui.position.top);
            console.log(ui.position.left);
            $(add).appendTo(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying that you want to leave the element being dragged in the exact position where it is dropped?

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your problem.

Comment: yes, so if i drop it in the center, i want it to stop there. at the moment its jumping to the top left

Comment: @ScottMitchell it was not 10 min after just a min or so

Comment: @Harsh definitely was not just one minute but I digress. Its fine

Comment: but it was definitely not 10 i can guarantee

Comment: i didnt even check u r answer else wouldnt have posted it..

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out anyway

```
$(add).css('left', ui.position.left-80+'px').css('top', ui.position.top-80+'px').appendTo(this);
```